# How do I delete/flush pm2 logs for only one app?

Tags: pm2

Can I flush the logs of only one app in Pm2?

Assuming my app id is 2

I tried

`pm2 flush 2`

but still it flushes all apps' logs.

Comment: Can you open an issue on https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4074

Comment: pm2 delete all; pm2 flush - does not work ... pm2 flush; pm2 delete all - works fine

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It was a bug in pm2.

I submitted an issue and they fixed it.

To solve it on your side, run these commands:

```
$ npm install pm2@latest -g
$ pm2 update
```

And it should work with the latest release.

Comment: Wow! Not all heroes wear cape. Good job mate.

Comment: well ... pm2 flush works - but it flushes ALL logs for ALL running processes.  If you do pm2 flush [n] to only clear the logs for a particular id number then it says "[PM2] Logs flushed" but the logs are untouched !  Moreover, pm2 flush [n] isn't shown as an option on the PM2 cheatsheet

Comment: I'm on PM2 4.5 and it's still buggy! https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4074#issuecomment-694216056

Comment: I'm on 5.1.2 and it doesn't work! I'm manually truncating the log files. :D

Comment: For those who came across this problem, please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/75166500/12783754. Good luck!

Answer (score 29):

pm2 logs are located in **.pm2/logs/**

PM2 LOGS COMMANDS :

**Show logs**

```
pm2 logs appName|appId --lines=100
```

**Show Error logs**

```
pm2 logs appName|appId --err --lines=100
```

**Empty log for specific app**

```
pm2 flush appName|appId
```

**Empty all log files**

```
pm2 flush
```

**Reload all logs**

```
pm2 reloadLogs
```

Answer (score 18):

You can flush log of **specific** **app** by mentioning `name` or `id`.

```
pm2 flush my_app_name // by name
pm2 flush my_app_id   // by id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try any one of the following commands to clear the logs in pm2,

```
pm2 flush        
pm2 flush appName|appId
```