# PM2 Flush not clearing logs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pm2

I run a Ubuntu server which is suddenly full because of pm2 logs taking 16GB. I tried `pm2 flush`. But this only clears the folder which took 4GB.

[image]

As root the ".pm2" folder is cleared but not logs folder. As my own user the folder is cleared but under the wrong username.

Here is showed running `pm2 flush` in root and admin user.

[image]

How do i clear it?

Comment: do you have solution so far?

Answer (score 2):

Hope I'm not too late. Alright, long story short.

The problem was within the code, the arguments passed aren't implemented correctly to deal with whatever logical comparison or verification they wanted. So as a result, the logs aren't being flushed.

I created an PR, which you can access [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/pull/5533). I think it will take some time for the maintainers to review the pull. It may not even get merged at all.

---

Anyways, if you want to apply and test the updated code to your system. You need to find where your PM2 package files are located.

To do this, just run the commands according to the package manager that you used to install pm2.

*Note: If you installed pm2 using `sudo`, you must ran the commands with `sudo` too.*

yarn =>  `yarn global dir`

npm  =>  `npm root -g`

After that, `cd` into the directory path that the command returned.

Then `cd` into `<..PATH..>/node_modules/pm2/lib/API`. You should see a file named `LogManagement.js`. Use `sudo cp` to make a copy of that file. So if there's any problem, you can still turn back.

Following, go to this github [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sailboat265/pm2/development-flush-patch/lib/API/LogManagement.js), and replace the entire `LogManagement.js` with the copied code.

Done! You should be able to run `pm2 flush "My App"` or something like `pm2 flush 1` as usual.

Answer (score 1):

you should try `pm2 flush <app_name>` it will remove the default output and error logs from .pm2/logs
the above command does not flush the merge logs for the specified app_name